# daisy chain addClass and removeatt, Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have the following query, which determines the value of a JSON object, and set's a Jquery panel css accordingly.

```
$('#pnlMissing').addClass((msg.d['MissingMessagesCount'] == "0") ? "panel-success" : "panel-danger");
```

I want to try and bit a bit clever, and also disable a hyperlink which is part of the overall panel..

```html
<div id="pnlMissing" class="panel">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Missing</h3>
    <span class="pull-right clickable" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-stitle="Toggle Missing"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <a id="lnkMissingMessages" href="#"><span id="missingCount"></span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know how to disable to hyperlink, if the conditional logic was an if/else, but not in this shorthand notation, which i'd like to use, as it's a lot clean.

So, my question, is if the above addClass logic is true, how can I also disable the hyperlink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: It appears IE does not honour the `disabled` property of anchors (and it only works on HTML5 browsers).

You will need to disable the click with a click handler and `e.preventdefault()`.This means your desired chaining will not work (*not without a custom jQuery extension that is*).

Example of custom jQuery method:

```
$.fn.disableLink = function(disable){
    // Turn off click and style
    this.off('click').css({'text-decoration': ''});
    if (disabled){
        // Enable click handler and style out underline
        this.on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        }).css({'text-decoration': 'none'});
    }
}
```

And use with

```
 .find('a').disableLink(msg.d['MissingMessagesCount'] == "0");
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/x0jo1L1o/2/

---

**Original Answer below**

You can conditionally set the disabled property using a boolean expression. For real properties (not plain attributes) it is always best to use `prop` and not `attr`. This has the added benefit that you can use `boolean` values (which makes more sense with the property values):

```
   .find('a').prop('disabled', (msg.d['MissingMessagesCount'] == "0"));
```

so in your example something like:

```
   $('#pnlMissing').addClass((msg.d['MissingMessagesCount'] == "0") ? "panel-success" : "panel-danger").find('a').prop('disabled', (msg.d['MissingMessagesCount'] == "0"));
```

For clarity/brevity I would always calculate the expression once like this:

```
  var disabled = msg.d['MissingMessagesCount'] == "0";
  $('#pnlMissing').addClass(disabled ? "panel-success" : "panel-danger").find('a').prop('disabled', disabled);
```

Comment: ok, so that worked a treat, but in true UI fashion, how to i prevent the end user from thinking the a link is clickable. Even though we have successfully prevented the click event from doing anything, I still give the impression, that they can click?

Comment: Style the link using a class and CSS that removes the underline (don't forget to remove it on hover too).

Comment: ok, so i was a little hasty... the panel is indeed disabled, but the click on the hyperlink is still active.

Comment: Of course... you need to apply it to the anchor within the panel. have adjusted example.

Comment: alas, exactly the same. tried it in another browser as well. IE, show the hyperlink greyed out, chrome, doesn't, but both still run when i click on the number.

Comment: Annoyingly, disabled does not work properly. You can enable or disable the anchor using a click handler.

Comment: Okay, added custom extension to allow the link behavior you wanted.  This avoid the need for the `disabled` property.